# Can anyone prove this sentence is in the passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

I don't believe it is, so I'd like the experts to chime in (I'm well versed in the passive, but thought maybe I'm missing some fine point familiar only to Ph.D's in linguistics).

The sentence in question is:

> The marathon participants were Harry, Luke and myself.

There are those who claim ***myself*** is correct because the sentence is in the passive (***???***), whereas if we switch it around,

> Harry, Luke and myself were the marathon participants,

it all of a sudden magically "becomes" the active voice, so you can no longer use ***myself***, you have to use ***I***.

I have scoured countless off-site sources as well as posts here, yet none of them seems to support the assertion that the first example is in the passive.

Not to mention the fact that if it were truly the passive, we'd have to use ***me***, not ***myself***.

> The marathon was participated in by Harry, Luke and me.

EDIT:  So I need proof that the first example is in the passive.

Comment: @ColinFine:  I am reacting to a very recent post here (I simply changed the words in my post), where (in the comments), I was told that a sentence like my example was passive.  Nobody came in to correct the statement.

Comment: Who are "those"? And please post the necessary links. The post is public, so there's no violation in posting the link. You can quote the comment, too. bearing in mind, we've all made mistakes and posted stupid comments in good faith. Only to return a couple of hours later (or days) and seen what complete fools we made of ourselves. P.S It's not a passive sentence , but a lot, a lot of people get this one wrong. They see a "were" and immediately think "passive"!

Comment: @Mari-LouA: See [I or me at the end of a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462261/i-or-me-at-the-end-of-a-list#comment1115253_462261) for context.

Comment: Why do you "need proof" of something that you can't find any evidence for and that other folks are telling you isn't true?

Comment: @1006a:  Because "I'm well versed in the passive, but thought maybe I'm missing some fine point familiar only to Ph.D's in linguistics."  I'm convinced it's not the passive, but the claim was made (since removed) that it was.  I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Can you explain what the relevance of the second example is? The question is answerable without it, and it only serves to confuse (as it did me).

Comment: Perhaps the question you mean to ask is, "***Is*** this sentence in the passive voice?"

Comment: @TannerSwett:  I originally had "How is this sentence passive?"  Someone edited that, so I edited his edit to better reflect what I was trying to get at.

Comment: What I was trying to get at, not too clearly, is whether you are happy to accept evidence *either way* about passivity. Right now your question reads more like "I'm pretty sure this isn't X, please prove it is X," which is confusing. It's also unclear whether you care about the reflexivity issue, or only passive vs active status.

Comment: @1006a:  In hindsight, I realize the question was ill-conceived  from the outset. I was trying to "prove" that the claim made in the comment (now deleted) @ the other post was wrong.  I've no Ph.D. in linguistics, so I don't know some of the "deeper things," so if someone could prove it WAS the passive, then I'd learn something new.  As it is, I was 99.9% sure it's NOT, so I phrased the question the other way. I'm hoping the mods will at least close this question (since it can't be deleted).

Comment: I think there's actually an interesting question lurking in there, if you're open to editing it. Something like "is there a reason why "myself" in *The participants were X, Y and myself* is OK when *X, Y and myself were the participants* sounds wrong, and does it have something to do with passive voice?"

Comment: Voting to close as there is no coherent question here. There's no passive so no 'proof' can be given.

Comment: @Mitch:  Yes, please do!

Comment: It's not passive, and "myself" should be changed to "I".

Comment: @AndreasBlass:  yep, that's my understanding, too.

Answer (score 3):

> There are those who claim "myself" is correct because the sentence is in the passive (???), whereas if we switch it around [...] it all of a sudden magically "becomes" the active voice, so you can no longer use myself, you have to use I.

This is just wrong. The presence of reflexive pronouns is not a test for passivity. My example below, "I introduced myself" is a counterexample.

Below, I'll detail when to use "myself" and show why it's unrelated to voice.

---

So, to me, a speaker of American English,

> The marathon participants were Harry, Luke and **myself**.

and

> The marathon participants were Harry, Luke and **me**.

are both *okay*, neither sounds totally grammatical.

The use of reflexive pronouns in English can be explained in [X' theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-bar_theory) using [c-command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-command). An argument c-commands another if it is higher in the deep structure of the sentence, and the reflexive is embedded within its complement.

Further, a reflexive takes its meaning from the argument that c-commands it. So in order to need to say "myself," that must be "I" higher in the tree.

Take this tree below. The determiner phrase "I" c-commands "myself" because "myself" is embedded within I'. This is starting to get technical, so basically, everything within I' is c-commanded by the DP "I" because I' is next to DP in the tree.

Here, "IP" stands for "inflection phrase" and isn't important to understanding the relationship.

[image: Grammatical reflexive parse tree.]

The same page has a second tree for the sentence *"Myself is so proud of me." There is no "I" higher in the tree than myself so this sentence is bad (we usually say "ungrammatical.") Don't worry about intermediate structure of the sentence.

[image: Ungrammatical reflexive parse tree]

I suspect that your first sentence, "The marathon participants were Harry, Luke, and myself" is acceptable to you because the person that "myself" refers to is a member of "marathon participants." Other people may not be able to interpret these phrases in the same way, and might find it marginal or "and me" better.

Likewise, *"Harry, Luke and myself were the marathon participants" is bad because there is nothing structurally above "myself."

Finally, you can say "The marathon was participated in by Harry, Luke and me" but not "The marathon was participated in by Harry, Luke and *myself." because there is nothing to c-command "myself" that is interpretable to refer to the same person.

Let me know if I can make this explanation more clear in any way.

---

Notes:

1. Trees are from the Wikibooks [Government and Binding Theory book](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Government_and_Binding_Theory).
2. In linguistics, we denote ungrammatical sentences/elements with an asterisk, as I've done above.
3. `X'` is pronounced "X-bar."

Comment: All the work you put into that post is commendable.  But it doesn't answer my question (please read it again), viz. how can somebody argue that the first example is in the passive?  I myself {chuckle} know well the usage of me, myself and I.  But the claim that the sentence in question is the passive, THAT is what I need to see proof of.

Comment: @Wordster It has nothing to do with voice. Can you link to a claim that the use of a reflexive pronoun necessitates the passive voice?

Comment: That's just IT:  I don't believe it's the passive voice.  I'm asking that the claim made at the other post be verified with "chapter and verse."

Comment: @Wordster What other post?

Comment: Sven Yargs posted the link above, 54 minutes ago.

Comment: @Wordster OK, I guess I'll go find the link then ... I don't know why Pam noted the voice, or why you switched it around to test for which form was OK. But, as I added to my answer, passive voice doesn't oblige reflexives, or vice versa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82501/discussion-between-wordster-and-azor-ahai).

Answer (score 2):

So, the sentence in question (again) is:

> The marathon participants were Harry, Luke and myself.

This sentence is not in the passive voice because the passive voice always involves a form of the verb "to be" followed by a past participle. There are no past participles in this sentence.

Comment: That's right -- 'were' is a form of 'to be', but there are no participles.  This is a 'copula', and they are about 'state of being'; neither active nor passive.

Comment: I would upvote this answer if it also mentioned the reflexive: the antecedent of 'myself' is the 'participants'; since the listener didn't know that the speaker would be included until the copula is processed, the use of '-self' is not needed (but not excluded either).

Answer (score 1):

The terminology '*passive/active* voice' was definitely misused there (it's active voice in both cases). However, replacement of 'myself' with 'me' (the original question there was about **I/me**) would give a pair of sentences, at least showing what the author of that comment was leading to: it was actually about **subject/object** (I/me) switching.

> The marathon participants were Harry, Luke and **me**.

(*participants* is the subject, *Harry, Luke* and *me* are objects)

> Harry, Luke and **I** were (that) marathon participants.

(*Harry, Luke* and *I* are subjects, *marathon* and *participants* are objects)